# How to create multiple picturebox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a simple game and I want to create `PictureBox`es as enemies but creating them by one by is hard so I tried to create a class for them.

But it's not working, can you please help?

```
public class enemies
{
    PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
    public Image img;

    public int enemy_top(int a)
    {
        pbox.Top = a;
        return a;
    }

    public int enemy_left(int b)
    {
        pbox.Left = b;
        return b;
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        enemies enemy1 = new enemies();
        enemy1.img = player.Image;
        enemy1.enemy_left(10);
        enemy1.enemy_top(20);

    ...
```

Comment: define: not working

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - It isn't enough to create them; they also need to be added to some parent, like form or a board control..

Comment: I am sorry, this is my first question. It's Winforms. There are no errors but nothing happens.

Comment: Please show your complete code - this snippet is of no use to solving your problem

Comment: If this is a separate class than from your form, then your PictureBox control and Timer components aren't a part of anything.  The PictureBox has to be added to the form's controls collection.